# Long URL string with ignored encoded string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, url, c#-4.0

I received a number of errors from my site last night having to do with URLs being too long, and the URLs had a referrer of something to the effect of http://www.domain.com/(F(MMAiUqbVfiNX75BZlCga8Aj-TZC1FC9CmzwHEW_HJiiedWLJgmOmz4TuXJVZAk8fuaeG1tP-q9Ss31KvU1zx7ozq7ZWjO80IizattGbJSdK-6Bz1delq4nzK-_FDjmnSnZv210JzGiWmQ4k1aNhCekMIIbQLvdaH9-aBlg2))/

I was testing this locally and that url actually works. In the Request.Url object, it seems to actually ignore the long encoded string in it (Request.Url.OriginalString is http://www.domain.com:80/, RelativePath is ~/).

The problem is that any UrlHelper will continue to append that on to the URL. So doing Url.Content("~/foo/bar") returns that long string with /foo/bar on the end.

It's almost like this is acting like and ApplicationPath or virtual directory, but that can't be since it works exactly the same on the live server and my local machine, but the 2 instances of IIS don't have the same virtual directories/applications set up.

Is there some significance to that string and some way to strip it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this has to do with Session Management and applying the 'cookieless' parameter to 'true', set this value to 'false' and your URL should be smaller.  Check out this article for details for [Session Management options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx), although if you need a cookieless environment, your session approach might need some rethinking...

Comment: My session is already using cookies (cookieless attribute is not on the sessionState tag in config, which I'm assuming defaults to false). Normally, I don't see this. But one user was able to access this. Apparently the even when using cookies, putting in the url must still work.

Comment: If you're not enabling this and this is happening occasionally, it might be possibly you're been targeted for Session hacking -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx#cookieless_topic5 and a possible way around this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc300500.aspx